# How to use ADFS in Java based web application

Tags: java, saml-2.0, adfs, adfs2.0

I am working on one Java based web application where I need to write Java code so that this web application can talk to ADFS for authentication purpose.

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

For ADFS 2.0, you can use WS-Federation or SAML.

You need to implement a client-side stack that will handle all the protocol details for you.

Refer: [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).

Comment: After much reading, i have decided to use spring saml 1.0.2 library in my Java based web application where SP will be my web app and IDP will be company's SSO.

Comment: Now, question is while initializing JKSKeyManager bean, do i need to use keystore.jks file. If yes, how i can get it. Please note that I have configured IDP with IDP provided certificate.